# Python appends symbol intended for breaking the loop to the final element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Seems like the problem is a little hard to explain in one sentence. Here's the code:

```
if url_or_doc_selection == 'URL':
    url_list = []
    while True:
        url_link = input('Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: ')
        if url_link == "q":
            break
        url_append = url_link.split('\n')
        if url_append != ['']:
            for e in url_append:
                url_list.append(e)
...
```

**What's intended to happen:** Users takes any list of URLs and pastes them into the prompt. Each URL is separated and added to a list. Once he/she is finished they input q to break the loop. Further code iterates over the list.

**What happens:** Everything works fine except for the final element as it gets "q" appended. Say user input is as follows:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence
```

After that user inputs `q` to break the loop. If I `print(url_list)`, the elements are

```
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal', 
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligenceq'
```

Of course, no such final link exists which breaks the rest of the code.

Same thing happens with any number of URLs. I've tried moving the `break` part all around, nothing seems to help. This is driving me crazy as it seems so simple yet I can't find any solution.

Comment: What's the point of `url_append = url_link.split('\n')`? `input()` will never return a string containing newline.

Comment: If the user is pasting instead of typing, I suspect the problem is that they didn't paste a newline after the last URL. So their `q` is on the same line.

Comment: The user needs to press Return after they paste.

Comment: You are correct, the '\n' does nothing. Fixed it. Pressing Return after pasting does work but it seems a bit confusing for the user. Is there any possible workaround?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it. If they don't press Return, they're typing on the same line as the last URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the last element of the list you are copying does not have a newline.

instead of copying the following:

```
google.com
google.com
```

copy this (without the \n, copy the two first lines and the start of the last line):

```
google.com
google.com
\n
```

Also, you do not need to split on '\n', since input already splits on each new line.

```
url_list = []
while True:
    url_link = input('Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: ')
    if url_link == "q":
        break
    url_list.append(url_link)
print(url_list)
```

There is an alternative to having the user copy the newline, which would be to have the input separated on commas.

```
url_list = []
while True:
    url_link = input('Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: ')
    if url_link == "q":
        break
    url_list.extend(url_link.split(","))
print(url_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work, although it might be a bit confusing for the user that they must have a newline when pasting.

Comment: Well then, you can do this (updated answer).

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it still attaches the q to the final element if there's no newline. Although the split seems to be unnecessary.

Seems like this is the best solution as Barmar mentioned there is no workaround to having a newline.

Comment: @Adomas what have you pasted that still attaches the q?

Comment: The same two URLs at the original answer without a newline after the last one. That still attaches a q to the final one even with the edited code in your answer.

I guess I'll just have to tell users to make a newline or rewrite parts of the code.

Comment: Well, yes, you can't get passed this. I think however, that the while loop is unnecessary, just ask for the whole bunch of URLs (either comma or newline separated) and then return the list. As I see it there is no need to multiple multiple url inputs (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```py
url_list = []
while True:
    url_link = input('Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: ')
    if url_link == "q":
        break
    url_list.append(url_link)

print(url_list)
```

Output:

```
Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: http://www.google.es/
Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: http://yahoo.es/
Enter URLs. Use "q" to stop: q
['http://www.google.es/', 'http://yahoo.es/']
```